# Is there a way to ignore the subdomain value in subdomain routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

According [to Lavarel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing), if I use subdomain routing for multiple subdomains, I have to pass the subdomain as the first argument of callbacks functions and controllers methods:

```
Route::domain('{sub}.example.org')->group(function () {
    Route::get('a', function ($sub) { /* ... */ });
    Route::get('b', function ($sub) { /* ... */ });
    Route::get('c/{c}', function ($sub, $c) { /* ... */ });
    Route::get('d/{d}', function ($sub, $d) { /* ... */ });
});
```

In other words, I have to carry the `$sub` variable everywhere. Assuming I don't care about its value, can I avoid this and just do something like this(this does not work for multiple argument):

```
Route::domain('{sub}.example.org')->group(function () {
    Route::get('a', function () { /* ... */ });
    Route::get('b', function () { /* ... */ });
    Route::get('c/{c}', function ($c) { /* ... */ });
    Route::get('d/{d}', function ($d) { /* ... */ });
});
```

If I do this, `$c` and `$d` will be the value of the subdomain.

Assuming I don't care about the subdomain value and I have many routes, is there a way to ignore it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can't just have it as a first argument and not use it?

Comment: Just that I have many routes and having a useless element in all methods is like a hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar thing with a dynamical prefix. Our solution was:

First we unset the parameter if it existed in the "App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php", which is the class your controllers most likely extend.

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    if (isset($parameters['clientident'])) {
        unset($parameters['clientident']);
    }

    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters);
}
```

This will unset the parameter for every function call in every controller and should do away with your problem.

But because we needed it in our route() function, we created a "App/Http/helpers.php" file for

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if (!isset($parameters['clientident'])) {
        // If the given value is not an array, wrap it in one.
        $parameters = Arr::wrap($parameters);
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $temp = ['clientident' => Auth::user()->getClientIdent()];
        }
        else if (request()->clientident) {
            $temp = ['clientident' => request()->clientident];
        }
        else {
            $temp = ['clientident' => 'general'];
        }
        $parameters = array_merge($parameters, $temp);
    }
    return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

and added the new helpers file in the "bootstrap/autoload.php"

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/helpers.php';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';         << this line was already here
```

This works because Taylor wrote an check in front of every helper function if it is already set, so it's pretty easy to override them

```
if (! function_exists('route')) {
    function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
}
```

is the code in the helpers.php in the Illuminate/Foundation directory.

I guess the route function has to be handled a little bit different in your case. You should be able to get the subdomain with domain helper functions and add it there as parameter back again, which is most likely much easier than our if elseif else case above.

Comment: np :) If you still have questions, just ask them here